# Creating Polynomial Function with Surface Area of Cylinder

Tags: functions, polynomials, circles

I've spent a few hours at this question but can't seem to get the right answer. I was hoping someone here can lead me in the right direction.

The question:

> A storage tank is to be constructed in the shape of a cylinder such
>   that the ratio of the radius, r, to the height of the tank is 1: 3.
>   Write a polynomial function to represent the surface area of the tank
>   in terms of r.

What I've Tried:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMUwn.jpg

The correct answer is $$f(r)=(6\pi r^2)(r+1).$$

I've tried Googling it and asking friends but still haven't come to the right answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer you state as "correct" is wrong. You check this through unit analysis: If radius and height are given in meters, the expression $r+1$ adds meters to a pure number, which is meaningless. Since you want area, the unit should become meters squared.

Your next-to-last line was correct: just finish the simplification for the really correct answer.

$$f(r)=2\pi r^2+6\pi r^2$$
$$=8\pi r^2$$

You can see that this has the right dimensions.

Comment: Thanks very much sir! This isn't the first time my textbook was wrong. I appreciate your help!